# Add data to table referenced with foreign key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Question` and `Options`. Question has `has_many` relation with Options. I need to add options to question whenever I create a new question. I have written the code but I am not able to send data to the options of Question model. Whenever I create the question and add options in the form, the options to that question are empty. Where is the mistake?

**Models**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :options

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**questions_controller.rb**

```
# GET /questions/new
  def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.options.build(params[:options])
  end

  # GET /questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /questions
  # POST /questions.json
  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    puts("---------------------Question options: --------------------------------------------")
    puts(@question.options)    
    @question.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: question, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :option1 %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :option2 %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I strongly recommend using a `FormObject` in place of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Here is a quick video on how to implement a `FormObject`. https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/form_objects

Also, there is a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634661/alternative-for-accepts-nested-attributes-for-maybe-virtus) on why `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is not a great option.